# What is black's idea in this puzzle?

Tags: puzzles, lichess

This is one of Lichess's puzzles, taken from a real game. Black is on the move.

```
[FEN "1r1q1rk1/5pbp/3pbnp1/1p1Np1B1/1p1nP3/P1N2P2/2P1B1PP/R2Q1RK1 b - - 0 1"]

1... Nxe4 2. Bxd8
```

The suggested move is Nxe4. However, I don't see how Black gains an advantage after White plays Bxd8.

Correction: The suggested move is Nxd5

Comment: When wondering about a solution, it helps to turn stockfish on (to the right above the moves list), click the puzzle starter move (the one that has the red box), and check how SF evaluates various moves (there will be a table of best moves above the moves table; you can execute them by clicking to see how the game evolves)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are quite right Nxe4 makes no sense. However Nxd5 does because then Qxd8 ends up losing 4 pieces for a queen:

```
[fen "1r1q1rk1/5pbp/3pbnp1/1p1Np1B1/1p1nP3/P1N2P2/2P1B1PP/R2Q1RK1 b - - 0 1"]

1...Nxd5 2. Bxd8 Nxc3 3. Qd2 Ncxe2+ 4. Kh1 Rfxd8
```

However if white doesn't take the queen and instead plays the next most obvious move, taking the knight with the e pawn, white still ends up losing a piece:

```
[fen "1r1q1rk1/5pbp/3pbnp1/1p1Np1B1/1p1nP3/P1N2P2/2P1B1PP/R2Q1RK1 b - - 0 1"]

1...Nxd5 2. exd5 Qxg5 3. dxe6 bxc3 4. exf7+ Rxf7 5.
```

Comment: I bet the OP meant Nxd5 and was just confused by the upside-down diagram. (When and why did it become fashionable to print chess diagrams upside down? I remember when diagrams always had White moving up the board.) But why is Nxd5 better than bxc3 which also wins a piece?